# How do I move the thumbnails in a dynamic slideshow

Tags: php, dynamic, slideshow

I am trying to move the thumbnails which are displayed vertically on the right hand side of the main image.
I would like to display them horizontally below the main image.

Slideshow is dynamic from a mysql database.

Php from the display page:

```
    <?php $sqli3 = "SELECT * FROM pro_img WHERE pro_id='$pid' ORDER BY img_id ASC LIMIT 0,1";
  $resulti3 = mysql_query($sqli3);
  $rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($resulti3);
  $description = str_replace( ' <br /><br /><br />', '</p>', $rs[pro_desc]);
  $description = str_replace( "<br /><br /><br />\r\n", "\n\r<p>", $description);
  ?>


 <div id=show class=slideshow>
    <div class=slideshow-images>
    <?php $sqli2 = "SELECT * FROM pro_img WHERE pro_id='$pid' ORDER BY img_id";
      $resulti2 = mysql_query($sqli2);
      $i=0;
      while($rsi2 = mysql_fetch_array($resulti2)){?>
    <a href=><img id=slide-<?php print $i?> src=images/pro-photo/normals/<?php print $rsi2[img_name]?> alt="<?php print $title.' Image '.($i+1)?>"/></a>
    <?php $i++;}?>
    </div>



<div class=slideshow-thumbnails><ul> <?php $sqli2 = "SELECT * FROM pro_img WHERE pro_id='$pid' ORDER BY img_id";
  $resulti2 = mysql_query($sqli2);
  $i=0;
  while($rsi2 = mysql_fetch_array($resulti2)){?>  
<li><a href=#slide-<?php print $i?>><img src=images/pro-photo/thumbnails/<?php print $rsi2[img_name]?> alt="<?php print $title.' Slide '.($i+1)?>"/></a></li><?php $i++;}?>

</ul></div>
</div>
```

And this is the slideshow CSS

```
 .slideshow {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;

}

.slideshow-images {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}       
.slideshow-images img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}       
.slideshow-thumbnails {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow {
    width: 508px;
    height: 375px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;

}
.slideshow a img {
    border: 0;
}

.slideshow-images {
    width: 508px;
    height: 381px;
}       
.slideshow-images-visible { 
    opacity: 1;
}   
.slideshow-images-prev { 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.slideshow-images-next { 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.slideshow-images img {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: static;
}

.slideshow-thumbnails * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px 0 0 16px;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
}
.slideshow-thumbnails a:hover {
    /*background-color: #005b79 !important;*/
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails img {
    display: block;
    height: 81px;
    width: 108px;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails-active {
    background-color: #0081ac;
    opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails-inactive {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: .5;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails {
    height: 381px;
    left: auto;
    right: -133px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 135px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
.slideshow-thumbnails ul {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Javascript here:

```
function VisualSlideShow(options){
if(options.effect&&options.effect.toLowerCase()=="fade"){options.effect="";}var path="";var regexp=/^(.*)visualslideshow\.js$/;$each($$("script"),function(item,index,object){if(regexp.test(item.src)){var res=regexp.exec(item.src);path=res[1];}});function writeScript(src,text){document.write("<scr"+"ipt type=\"text/javascript\""+(src?" src=\""+path+src+"\"":"")+">"+(text||"")+"</scr"+"ipt>");}writeScript("slideshow.js");if(options.effect){writeScript("slideshow."+options.effect.toLowerCase()+".js");}if(options.sound){writeScript("swfobject.js");}window.addEvent("domready",function(){if(options.sound){window.vssSoundListener={onInit:function(){}};$(options.id).grab(new Element("div",{id:"vssSound"}));swfobject.createSWF({data:path+"player_mp3_js.swf",width:"1",height:"1"},{allowScriptAccess:"always",loop:true,FlashVars:"listener=vssSoundListener&loop=1&autoplay=1&mp3="+options.sound},"vssSound");}var Instance;if(options.effect){Instance=new Slideshow[options.effect](options.id,null,options);}else{Instance=new Slideshow(options.id,null,options);}if(!window.visualslideshow){window.visualslideshow=[];}window.visualslideshow[window.visualslideshow.length]=Instance;var h=$$("#"+options.id+" div.slideshow-images");if(h&&t){var c=new Element("div",{styles:{position:"absolute",right:0,bottom:0,padding:"0 3px 2px",'background-color':"#EEE",'z-index':999999},events:{contextmenu:function(eventObject){return false;}}});




}});}

VisualSlideShow({"duration":2000,"delay":5000,"id":"show","width":508,"height":381,"captions":true,"controller":false,"thumbnails":true,"loop":true,"paused":false,"effect":"Fade"});
```

Comment: position: absolute, top: 0 ... animate .. top: 100, not working?  For example have you tried using `JavaScript` Because, ah hum, I not see any JavaScript above

Comment: Sorry, added the javascript:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out the solution to this problem.

The PHP does not change only the css and the javascript.

Both are below.

CSS

```
.slideshow {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.slideshow-images {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}       
.slideshow-images img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}       
.slideshow-thumbnails {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow {
    width: 630px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slideshow a img {
    border: 0;
}

.slideshow-images {
    width: 630px;
    height: 434px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}       
.slideshow-images-visible { 
    opacity: 1;
}   
.slideshow-images-prev { 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.slideshow-images-next { 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.slideshow-images img {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: static;
}

.slideshow-thumbnails * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative; 
}
.slideshow-thumbnails a:hover {
    background-color: #CCC !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails img {
    display: block;
        height: 83px;
    width: 120px;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails-active {
    background-color: #7A7A7A;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails-inactive {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: .5;
}
.slideshow-thumbnails {
    top: 420px;
    height: 180px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 630px;
    overflow: auto; 
}
.slideshow-thumbnails ul {
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 630px;
}
.slideshow {
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.slideshow-captions {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font: normal 12px/22px Arial, sans-serif;
    left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 580px;   /* 100% */
    z-index: 10000;
}
.slideshow-captions-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
.slideshow-captions-visible {
    opacity: .7;
}


.slideshow-controller {
    background: url(../images/controller.png) no-repeat;
    height: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -21px 0 0 -96px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 192px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.slideshow-controller * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slideshow-controller-hidden { 
    opacity: 0;
}
.slideshow-controller-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow-controller a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
}
.slideshow-controller a.active {
    background-position: 0 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li {
    list-style: none;
}
.slideshow-controller li.first a {
    background-image: url(../images/controller-first.png);
    left: 13px;
    width: 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li.prev a {
    background-image: url(../images/controller-prev.png);
    left: 46px;
    width: 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li.pause a {
    background-image: url(../images/controller-pause.png);
    left: 79px;
    width: 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li.play a {
    background-position: 32px 0;
}
.slideshow-controller li.play a.active {
    background-position: 32px 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li.next a {
    background-image: url(../images/controller-next.png);
    left: 112px;
    width: 32px;
}
.slideshow-controller li.last a {
    background-image: url(../images/controller-last.png);
    left: 145px;
    width: 32px;
}


.slideshow-loader {
    height: 28px;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 28px;
    z-index: 10001;
}
.slideshow-loader-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
.slideshow-loader-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function VisualSlideShow(options){
if(options.effect&&options.effect.toLowerCase()=="fade"){options.effect="";}var path="";var regexp=/^(.*)visualslideshow\.js$/;$each($$("script"),function(item,index,object){if(regexp.test(item.src)){var res=regexp.exec(item.src);path=res[1];}});function writeScript(src,text){document.write("<scr"+"ipt type=\"text/javascript\""+(src?" src=\""+path+src+"\"":"")+">"+(text||"")+"</scr"+"ipt>");}writeScript("slideshow.js");if(options.effect){writeScript("slideshow."+options.effect.toLowerCase()+".js");}if(options.sound){writeScript("swfobject.js");}window.addEvent("domready",function(){if(options.sound){window.vssSoundListener={onInit:function(){}};$(options.id).grab(new Element("div",{id:"vssSound"}));swfobject.createSWF({data:path+"player_mp3_js.swf",width:"1",height:"1"},{allowScriptAccess:"always",loop:true,FlashVars:"listener=vssSoundListener&loop=1&autoplay=1&mp3="+options.sound},"vssSound");}var Instance;if(options.effect){Instance=new Slideshow[options.effect](options.id,null,options);}else{Instance=new Slideshow(options.id,null,options);}if(!window.visualslideshow){window.visualslideshow=[];}window.visualslideshow[window.visualslideshow.length]=Instance;var h=$$("#"+options.id+" div.slideshow-images");if(h&&t){var c=new Element("div",{styles:{position:"absolute",right:0,bottom:0,padding:"0 3px 2px",'background-color':"#EEE",'z-index':999999},events:{contextmenu:function(eventObject){return false;}}});




}});}

VisualSlideShow({"duration":2000,"delay":5000,"id":"show","width":630,"height":420,"captions":false,"controller":false,"thumbnails":true,"loop":true,"paused":false,"effect":"Fade"});
```

I hope this helps other people looking for a mysql driven slideshow.